# react-native-google-signin package is not giving refresh token

Tags: react-native

I am implementing google api in my React-Native app and using react-native-google-signin package for google sign-in/oauth.

While using the code

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"], // what API you want to access on behalf of the user, default is email and profile
  iosClientId: <FROM DEVELOPER CONSOLE>, // only for iOS
  webClientId: <FROM DEVELOPER CONSOLE>, // client ID of type WEB for your server (needed to verify user ID and offline access)
  offlineAccess: true // if you want to access Google API on behalf of the user FROM YOUR SERVER
  hostedDomain: '' // specifies a hosted domain restriction
  forceConsentPrompt: true // [Android] if you want to show the authorization prompt at each login
  accountName: '' // [Android] specifies an account name on the device that should be used
})
.then(() => {
  // you can now call currentUserAsync`enter code here`()
});
```

Although I have **offlineAccess: true**, still, I don't get refresh token to be used after original token expires. How to get refresh token with this package? Or what to do when token expires? My service is silent background worker and can't ask user credentials with giving the UI.